# Do operations with JSON values

Tags: php, json

I need to sum all values of "initialContractualPrice" in http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate).

I ned to do the operations in php.

who know that can help me?

thank you very much ;)

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Are you sure allowed to access those JSON data with proper consent ? It is on `gov` domain. If not get ready to deal with the consequences.

Comment: @sankar is thier any problem? should i delete my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate)');
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data as $dat){
echo $dat->publicationDate;
}
```

You can also use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the structure

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it.

```
// Get json from url
$url = 'http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate)';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
// Decode json into an array
$json = json_decode($content, true);

// Set default
$total = 0;

// Loop through the array created when decoding json
foreach ($json as $key) 
{
    // remove symbol from the end leaving only digits
    $value = substr(utf8_decode($key['initialContractualPrice']), 0, -1);
    // remove the decimal point
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
    // replace the comma with a decimal point
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    // add this number to the total value
    $total += $value;
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: i save all data from the webpage "http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate)" and i need to reed it and do the operations... do you know why i can do it?